# Prestashop how can i get the posted input value under order page?

Tags: php, module, prestashop

I'm try to make a module

i have a hook `hookDisplayBeforeCarrier` here. I created a input

> `<input type="date" value="2017-02-14">`

How can i get the this input value?

My codes:

```
public function hookDisplayBeforeCarrier()
    {

        $output = $this->context->smarty->fetch($this->local_path.'views/templates/frontend/delivery.tpl');

        return $output;
    }
```

Tpl file:

```
<div class="deliverydate">
        <p>  {l s='Select Delivery Date' mod='selectdeliverydate'} : <input type="date" value="2017-02-14"></p>
    </div>
```

Comment: what do you mean with "how can i get this input value"? does the input field show in page? what's the prestashop version?

Comment: Just add `name="your_variable"` to your input tag.

Answer (score 0):

First of all add name="your_variable" to the input tag.

To save its value you can add a button with this input and on clicking that button you have to send an ajax request to fetch its value and take appropriate action.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can try it with this module
https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/589259-m%C3%B3dulo-selector-fecha-en-pedido/